# After calling 'add_key_down_handler(argmt)' how could I set it up so that when one of the keys is pressed the handler stops running? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, brython

For instance in this code:

```
def check(event):
     if event.key == "a":
          function()

add_key_down_handler(check)
```

If the key "a" is clicked again after this, `function()` should not run.

---

The way I tried to solve this was to do the following:

```
def check(event):
     if event.key == "a":
          function()
          remove_key_down_handler(check)

add_key_down_handler(check)
```